# How do I emebed css at compile-time using AS3 (just like the <fx:style> tag)?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm working in a Flash Builder 4 Actionscript project and trying to figure out how to embed a css file into the project at "compile-time". Just as we did when we use MXML's `<fx:Style>` tag.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Embed your stylesheet with the octet-stream mime-type 

[Embed(source="assets/stylesheet.css", mimeType="application/octet-stream")] 
private var stylesCSS:Class;   

public function createStyleSheetObject():StyleSheet 
{
    // create a new StyleSheet instance
    var styleSheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
    styleSheet.parseCSS(new stylesCSS().toString());
    return styleSheet; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [Flex 3 help documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_05.html#165272):

> You can specify a CSS file as an argument to the `source-path`compiler argument. This lets you toggle among style sheets with that compiler argument.

Comment: If you're willing to do it in the AS3 side, I guess you're then going for applying stylesheets at runtime...